# apache CsrfPreventionFilter and 404 error

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat7

I am using `org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter` to prevent Cross-Site Request Forgery but facing problem when user clicks on the link which lands him to HTTP 404. After that for all the requests, it starts throwing 403.

For example when user tries to download a csv file which isn't there anymore, he is redirected to 404.jsp page. The link to csv file is something like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/mc-portal/uploaded_numbers/03002790541_20150509144859.csv?org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=5F5CC51CFC21FD96B09E93F40666DC44
```

After that no matter which link user tries to visit it always throw following 403:

```
"NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - http://localhost:8080/mc-portal/logout?org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=8A9F00AA9B26A285D7FC0C3FBE160E61"
```

The 404.jsp error page is already placed in entryPoints param value in web.xml:

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CsrfFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>entryPoints</param-name>
            <param-value>/index.jsp,/login,/home.jsp,/logout,/404.jsp</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>nonceCacheSize</param-name>
            <param-value>
                5
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CsrfFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```